# How to create the administrative side, to add products to my database?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to `add products` to my database. I am creating a PHP page to allow me to select the artist by name or enter a new one, upload an image, and enter the details of the product.

When I run my code, I am not getting no where forward.
I get an error on this line of my code:

```php
<p>
  <b>Print Name: </b> 
  <input type="text" name="print_name" size="30" maxlength="60"
      value="<?php if (isset($_POST['print_name']))
                       echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['print_name']);?>" />
</p>
```

The error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING

Comment: this is my code: <p><b>Print Name:</b> <input type="text" name="print_name" size="30" maxlength="60"
value="<?php if (isset($_POST['print_name'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['print_name']);?>"
/></p>

Comment: share value of `$_POST['print_name']` ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything syntactically wrong with that line, are you sure you're not getting the error from somewhere else? How did you determine that this is the line with the error?

Comment: when i run the code in google chrome it gives me the line error @rid

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like below :

```
<p>
  <b>Print Name: </b> 
  <input type="text" name="print_name" size="30" maxlength="60" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['print_name'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['print_name']) : '' ;?>"
/>
</p>
```

You are using **Unary** operator in wrong way :

The structure of **unary** is :

```
<?php echo (condition) ? true : false ; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's still giving the same error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: Remove htmlspecialchars() function and check. Still you facing the issue ?

Comment: If you faces the issue still please change as like : {htmlspecialchars($_POST['print_name'])}

Comment: I have removed the htmlspecialchars() function and checked it, didnt work did this <p>
  <b>Print Name: </b> 
  <input type="text" name="print_name" size="30" maxlength="60" value="<?php echo 
  (isset($_POST['print_name'])) ? {htmlspecialchars($_POST['print_name'])} : '' ;?>"

/>            
</p>

Comment: still same error

Comment: This might be silly, Give a try, Remove all php code which is inside value="", Still you facing the issue?

Comment: Thank you very much the error is not for this code now, but i have another error in this code <p><input type="radio" name="artist" value="existing" <?php if (isset($_POST['artist']) && 
($_POST['artist'] == 'existing')) echo ' checked="checked" '; ?>/> Existing => if you can help me

Comment: the same error as the previous but in different code @Muthu17

Comment: give us line numbers errors and show us which line is error-line

Answer (score 0):

You can try this you have to start and over curly brackets

```
<input type="text" name="print_name" size="30" maxlength="60"  value="<?php if (isset($_POST['print_name'])){
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['print_name']);}?>">
```